# openCV library GLIBC compile error

Tags: linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, pascal, glibc

I tried to compile an openCV application for RapsberryPi 2 with Lazarus-IDE(Pascal compiler) on Ubuntu x64 PC.

But, the compiler shows error :
[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA8Wj.jpg)

Pre-compiled openCV library version : 2.4.8
Pre-compiled glibc library version : 2.19

Any idea?

Comment: Read the error messages. They say what is wrong. Either modify the code so it doesn't need the missing functions, or use versions of the linked  software that provide them.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I checked it already. the libraries work fine in native build.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that you are trying to link against a glibc version older than 2.15, while the library was compiled against glibc 2.15 or later.

If your target does not support glibc 2.15, you will have to recompile the library instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer, and Sorry for late. I think, the compiler links x64 GLIBC instead of target GLIBC library file. the compiling environment is Ubuntu desktop.